# Can I use carotenoids to make a creature's blood and flesh purple?

Tags: science-based, xenobiology

I've done research and I've decided purple carotenoids and/or carotenoid protein complexes is what I want to use to color a creature. It doesn't involve a different type of blood, and its antioxidant properties are beneficial(any other benefits?). I know plants make it and earth animals can't, but is it theoretically possible that an animal could make it? And what shade of purple would the normal red iron based blood be if the purple was added(I'd like a dark purple)? How would it be made(simplified version please)? How expensive would it be to make so much?
Are there any purple pigments that would be better?

Comment: Yes, animals can either make or extract from food all sorts of pigments, including carotenoids. When you see red, or orange, or yellow in a bird's plumage, the color is most likely given by carotenoid pigments which the bird's body obtained from food, modified if needed, and used where required. But then comes the no, I have no idea why you would think that the pigments would circulate in the blood in any appreciable quantity. They most usually don't, why would they? I don't know of any example where an animal's pigments circulate in its blood in sufficient quantity to change its color.

Comment: P.S. The exception to the reds, oranges and yellows in the plumage of birds being produced by carotenoids which the bird obtained from food is parrots. Parrots make their own [psittacofulvin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psittacofulvin), which is not a carotenoid and has an entirely different chemical structure.

Comment: @AlexP there are some lizards that have green flesh and blood due to biliverdin

Answer (score 4):

**Yes.**

Make your animal any colour you want. This is a non-problem.

Most people will be happy to accept any colour under the sun. There are purple birds and purple plants after all. Why not purple animals?

The chemical nature of the pigment of your imaginary animal is both (a) highly technical and (b) completely uninteresting. Too advanced for most readers. The small number of molecular biologists reading will, I am sure, be used to suspending disbelief over much bigger things.

Comment: This isn't for a book. This is for me continually and obsessively seeking knowledge to understand the alien critters in my head worlds. It is interesting for me. I like to understand how things work. I do put my creatures and character info online though.

Answer (score 0):

Because DNA is basically universal across most, if not all, living things, one can surmise that there is a stable biological state on the spectrum between carrot and whatever your reference animal is. This state could be undiscovered because there was no evolutionary need to do so.

as to what color and if it might cause health issues that may arise is beyond my capability, much less price.

Regardless, if the environment demands it, mother nature will answer in kind.